# AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. in IE and Edge browsers

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, adal.js

Few users getting this error, We did some workaround to fix this issue like added the login.microsoftonline.com and site url to the trusted sites. I have seen some one raised same question [here(323)](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/323). One of them given suggession like do forceful login (ex: authContext.login()). In my case when i browse the site login page will not come in IE and Edge as it is authenticated through system credentials.

Is forceful login is a good approach or not? am not sure here.
They are not concluded/finalized any solution in the mentioned question above.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue.?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Some of the possible reasons for getting this error and the corresponding solutions/workarounds have been documented in the ADAL.js [FAQ](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs#q6-aadsts50058-a-silent-sign-in-request-was-sent-but-no-user-is-signed-in) topic.

If there are issues limited to Edge or IE, this is a browser security settings constraint and the known workarounds are listed [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/Known-issues-on-Edge).

In other cases where the session for the current user has expired or is invalid in AAD, you will need to prompt the user for login with an interactive request.